# New kitten lunges at older cat

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

We adopted a 1ish year old stray cat. We already had a 10 year old cat. We did a slow introduction and all seemed to be going well. Most of the day they retreat to different rooms, occasionally they’ll sit near each other and rest. Our old cat sometimes seems fine and then other times she is very upset and vocal when the newer cat walks by her or goes newer her.

Recently our young cat has started charging and swatting (nails sheathed) at our older cat. Our older cat just swiped at the new cat with her nails out. The young cat retreated.

Is this the young cat playing and my older cat isn’t socialized/doesn’t get it? Is there anything I can do to help their relationship or help teach the younger cat to keep her distance? We’ve had her for almost 4 months.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like "play with me!". The older cat will handle it

Comment: My experience is that cats of different ages are often like children of different ages. The younger ones have much more energy and want to play too much for the older ones to enjoy. They will eventually come to an understanding of how much play is too much play, but you should be an alternative play partner for the young one.

Comment: @Elmy My experience is the same as yours, and I agree about having an alternative play partner for the young one.  I think your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Welcome Katie! If you haven't already, you will likely want to ensure both animals have all shots recommended by your vet.  This is especially true since there could be a tiny bit of broken skin and bloodshed until both animals are comfortable with each other.